# Failed to serialize user into session error

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport.js

I am trying to create an authentication with Node.js, Passport, and MySQL.

This is my local-login strategy:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField: 'email',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '" + email + "'", function(err, rows) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
                }
                console.log(`Email found ${email}`)


                bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0].Password, function(err, res) {

                    if (res) {
                        //Password matched
                        console.log('Password matched')
                        // all is well, return successful user



                        return done(null, rows[0]);

                    } else {
                        //password did not match
                        console.log('Password did not match')
                        return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata
                    }
                })


            })


        }));
```

I get the console message saying "Password matched" but it looks like

`return done(null,rows[0])` is throwing the error message. My post route for login is

```
router.post("/login",passport.authenticate('local-login'),function(req,res){
    res.redirect("/users")
    })
```

I am also serializing and deserializing as per the passport documentation:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query("select * from users where id = " + id, function(err, rows) {
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});
```

This is my passport initialize and passport session code

```
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret:"willsecurelater",
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false

}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())
```

Comment: Can you check if `err` in the callback to `passport.deserializeUser()` is null or not?

Comment: Looks like `passport.deserializeUser()` function is not  even being executed. Adding console.log inside the function gives me nothing. Adding console.log(err) inside the query execution also gives me nothing

Comment: Have you done `passport.initialize()` and `passport.session()` correctly and in order?

Comment: The last console message that I get is `console.log('Password matched')` . Looks like the code stops at `return done(null, rows[0]);` but I am not sure why.

Comment: I think it is right because my `local-signup` is working properly but `local-login` is not. I have edited my question to show you my order as well

Comment: My code is based on this https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84

Comment: I fixed the problem. In MySQL database my `id` column was named `ID` so passport could not even serialize the user with `user.id` because the id column should have been capitalized